# Appium - Reduce Screenshot Time

Tags: android, python, ios, appium, python-appium

I have just started learning Appium to Automate Android ans iOS applications.
I am using Python with OpenCV for image recognition to automate an App made with Unity.
But taking screenshots consume a big amount of time. 
Is there a way to reduce this time, or some faster tool or framework to do this?

```
browser = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
screen = browser.get_screenshot_as_base64()
img = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(screen)))
```

My issue is with the `browser.get_screenshot_as_base64()`, that takes between 7 and 10 seconds. I also tried `browser.save_screenshot("image.png")` but with the same results

Thanks in advance
and sorry for my english

Comment: can you share how you are taking the screenshots?

Comment: Hi, i have just addedd

Comment: I am not familiar with Image.open(). What is the purpose of the line `img = Image.open(BitesIO(base64.b64decode(screen)))` ? It looks like you take a screenshot, encode it to base 64, then you decode it from base 64 into the variable img

Comment: Exactly, The Image.open() from the PIL library so then i can do some stuff with it. But the get_screenshot is what takes so much time. I also try:
`browser.save_screenshot("filename.png")` but with the same results